# RegEx to contain at least one dot

Tags: regex

Here's my regex :

```
\b(https?|www)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]*[.]{1,256}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong because I use RegEx very rarely.
The idea of the last `[.]{1,256}` was to make sure of having at least one "." in.
So, without it I got "https://www" match, so I wanted to make sure that at least one dot exists.
But with the expression above, it cuts to the first dot, not the whole thing.

Comment: Try `\b(https?|www)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,;]*\.[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you're trying to validate a URL, the language you're using probably already has code built in that will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `www` before `://` does not make much sense, it can occur after `://`, so it can be removed.

Both `[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*` and `[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]*` can match an empty string, and the `[.]{1,256}` at the end of your pattern matches 1 to 256 dots, that is why you get matches up to a dot.

You may refactor the pattern to match all those chars you allow before a dot, then match a dot, and then match any amount of chars you allow, together with a dot:

```
\bhttps?://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,;]*\.[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*
```

Here,

- `[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,;]*` - matches 0 or more chars you allow but a dot
- `\.` - this matches a dot
- `[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*` - 0 or more allowed chars including a dot.

So, at least 1 dot will get matched.

Comment: If javascript have to scape the slash after `:` --> `\b(https?|www):\/\/[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,;]*\.[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*`
I think also the `www` doesnt make sense there

Comment: @YuriAps If you use a constructor notation, there is no need to escape `/`: ``const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`\b(https?|www)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,;]*\.[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*`);``

Comment: why would some put `www` before `://`?

Comment: @YuriAps It was not me, it was in OP regex. The problem was to make sure there is only one dot in the domain part. If this `www` worked for OP, I did not touch it. I edited the answer to avoid further confusion.